# datetime.strptime() conversion failure for year 10000

Tags: python, date, datetime, strptime

The below python code worked fine until 12-31-9999.

It threw error once I changed the date to 01-01-10000 (see the screen shot attached)

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
 
          
myNewDate = "12-31-9999"
            
myNewDateTime = datetime.strptime(myNewDate, '%m-%d-%Y').date()
print (myNewDateTime)
```

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Isn’t there something about the year 2038?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), only 4 digit years are supported.

The years are limited by the 1989 C standard.

Comment: Also https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339 allows just 4 digits [a standard on recommended way to encode dates in newer internet standards]. It makes not much sense to predict dates in 8000 years.

Answer (score 1):

`%Y` signifies a 4 digit year, the last 0 is unmatched by the pattern. You can't use python datetime to work with years beyond 9999: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.MAXYEAR